# How to use OBO-flow with Flow app and Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0

I have a Power Automate flow in which I call [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/token) with the following body:

```
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id={clientId}
&client_secret={clientSecret}
&resource={app_registration}
```

The access token I receive from the call is being sent to an Azure Function app that needs to connect to Dynamics CRM. The Azure function tries to make a call to the Microsoft Identity Platform again with the same ClientId and ClientSecret and using the received bearer token as a `new Userassertion(req.GetBearerToken())`

The full relevant code in the Azure Function is as follows:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential("{clientId}", "{clientSecret}");
AuthenticationResult res = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation", credential, new UserAssertion(req.GetBearerToken()));
string bearerTokenforCRM = res.AccessToken;
```

> A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in

I think I can't use the bearer token acquired from the /token call in the Flow app to acquire a new token on behalf of the user that started the flow app.

In the App Registration in Azure, I added the Azure function in the menu "Expose an Api" and added "Dyanmics CRM" in the menu API Permissions with permission name "user impersonation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are a bit overcomplicating things - you can use the connection strings with ClientId/ClientSecret in order to connect to Dataverse using the following nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client
You can use the following article in order to build your connection string - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect
Basically it should look like the following:

```
AuthType=ClientSecret;
url=https://contosotest.crm.dynamics.com;
ClientId={AppId};
ClientSecret={ClientSecret}
```

In order to impersonate and perform actions on behalf of another user you can set the CallerId property of the service instance - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.callerid?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-xrm-tooling-connector-crmserviceclient-callerid

Comment: But it’s important for the function app to call the Dynamics function in the context of the user that initiated the request

Comment: In order to impersonate and perform actions on behalf of other user you can set CallerId property of the service instance - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.callerid?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-xrm-tooling-connector-crmserviceclient-callerid

Comment: This comment did the trick. It also fits the question better so if you change your answer to what your comment said I will accept it

Comment: I've updated the answer with the added comment.